# Xerox workcentre 7845 scan to email, test email works but unable to send scanned documents

Tags: smtp, multi-function-printer

I have a Xerox Workcentre 7845 and have scan to email setup with Gmail settings.
Host name : smtp.gmail.com:465
Encryption type: SSL/TLS
Device name: xxxxxx@gmail.com

It was working just fine until a few days ago and then it stopped. I did a test email and it worked fine but it cannot send the scanned documents.
I tried restarting the machine but it doesn't help. I am a bit curious as to what is going on. Does changing the settings on the printer will make a difference considering that the test email works fine?

Answer (score -1):

The Gmail security settings were changed by Google at that time. Unfortunately without a lot of notice. Please contact Xerox Support for the instructions on how to configure the device for the new settings and if new software is needed on your device.

Comment: Can you link to the GMail settings notification?